# Dimension/Size of image in HTML/CSS "breaking" based on its position

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

I'm coding in HTML/CSS and when I have my image position set to `absolute`, everything works fine. But the issue is that once I set it to `relative`, its border goes all weird. Here are some examples:

Absolute - CSS:

```
.dashboard-button {
  position: absolute;
  border: thin red solid;
}
```

Absolute - Image:
https://gyazo.com/43135c7c665aceb4cdb232f50887d446

Relative - CSS:

```
.dashboard-button {
  position: relative;
  border: thin red solid;
}
```

Relative - Image:
https://gyazo.com/661182fb53acfb6b732a70b3b00ca38a

As you can see, with `relative`, the border of the image just flattens itself out. I've tried setting the `height` to the image's height. I've tried setting the `height` to `100%`, and I've even tried something crazy. I set the `height` to `500px`, just to see if it would do anything. It didn't. I'm not sure what's wrong here but any answers are much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a snippet with HTML and CSS, thanks

Comment: @ovokuro hey I just fixed it, just needed to add `inline-block` to the `display` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution... All I had to do was set the `display` to `inline-block`. Here's my new CSS code:

```
.dashboard-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin red solid;
}
```